# Open File in PyMuPdf via a POST data

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

I want to test PyMuPdf against pdfplumber.

In pdfplumber I use this - works fine.

```
file = request.FILES.get('file') 

with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:

    for pg, element in enumerate(pdf.pages):

        current_page = pdf.pages[pg]
```

When I try to open the same file with PyMuPdf I get this.

```
doc = fitz.open(file)

'fitz.FileNotFoundError: no such file: 'testpages.pdf'
```

This is my POST data.

```
print(request.FILES)

<MultiValueDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile:testpages.pdf (application/pdf)>]}>
```

Not sure what the difference is?  Thank you so much.

Comment: maybe helpful [link](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/64)